# Using a Role table with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

Each user has a single role.

User `:name :role_id`

Role `:name`

user.rb

```
belongs_to :role
```

role.rb

```
has_many :users
```

ability.rb - I expected this to work through the belong_to/has_many relationship -

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role.name == "Admin"
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end
```

This was nilClass error, but failing that, why do I get "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#index - Couldn't find Role without an ID" using the following?

I'm logged in as a user with role_id: 4, which is the index for name: "Admin".

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
     user ||= User.new # guest user

     if user.role_id = nil
       user.role_id = 5
     end

     if Role.find(user.role_id).name == "Admin"
       can :manage, :all
     end
  end
end
```

I think I have a pretty fundamental error in my understanding of the relationship between rails models.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `app/models/user.rb` you should have relation:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
```

same thing in `app/models/user.rb`:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Please check, that you have `roles` and `roles_users` tables in your database.
Then, you should check, that in your `roles` table are roles you want.
You can do it by `rails console` in your application folder:

```
1.8.7-p371 :005 > Role.find(:all, :select => 'id, name')
 => [#<Role id: 1, name: "super_admin">, #
     <Role id: 2, name: "owner">, #
     <Role id: 3, name: "admin">]
```

Then in `app/models/ability.rb` you can use:

```
if user.role? :super_admin
    can :manage, :all
end
```

You'll find more information in cancan wiki:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. I have both roles and users tables - you're saying I need to add a table roles_users, consisting of role_id and user_id?

Comment: Yes, look there http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many
I think, that should help in your case.